# Annihilator of a flat ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Let $R$ be a commutative ring and let $I$ be a finitely generated flat ideal of $R$. Let $J=\mathrm{Ann}(I)$. How can one prove that $I\cap J=0$?

This can be found as a remark in the paper of Vasconcelos, [On finitely generated flat modules](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-138-00/S0002-9947-1969-0238839-5/S0002-9947-1969-0238839-5.pdf), below Corollary 3.1.

Comment: "Off-topic" is a bit of a misnomer, but the paragraph beneath gives the core of the reason: the question is 'missing context or other details'.  Most likely, the perception was that the question being asked was a homework question, and that no effort was shown in it.

Comment: Anyone who has seen the standard books on commutative algebra can tell that this question is not in the exercises in any of those books. Yes, still it could be a HW problem, but it is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint.** Work locally, and recall that [over a local ring any finitely generated flat module is free](https://books.google.ro/books?id=nfpzBAAAQBAJ&pg=PA11&lpg=PA11&dq=%22finitely+generated+flat+module+over+a+local+ring%22&source=bl&ots=GSPVilfguI&sig=0Pu3ASwI0b2ZjmwhDrTeGTWR7io&hl=ro&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwidgN3w477MAhUBkRQKHTQRDLYQ6AEIOzAH#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: with your answer, it seems to me that one can prove that $J=0$ because $J_p=(0:I)_p=(0:I_p)=0$ for all $p\in Spec(R)$. The last equality is because $I_p$ is principally generated by a non-zero divisor as it is a free $R_p$ module. What is wrong here?

Comment: @user114539 I don't think $I_p$ should be $\ne0$ for all $p$.

Comment: As far as I know the zero module is free. (See also [here](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/Algebra/Chapter4.pdf) on page 9.)